# How make short[] from input stream

Tags: android, audio

I'm working on an audio recording system. How make array short[] from input stream in java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, use `InputStream.read(byte[] buffer)` to store your data into a byte array. Then use something like this to convert it into SHORT[].

```
byte[] bBuffer; // your buffer containing your byte[] data
short[] sBuffer;
ByteBuffer.wrap(bBuffer).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().get(sBuffer);
```

Although unless you really need a short[], I would do processing using bytes on the fly so it's more optimized.

To go the other way, you can just use `put()` into the short buffer representation of the [ByteBuffer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html). So, something like:

```
byte[] bBuffer;
short[] sBuffer;  // your buffer containing your byte[] data
yourByteBuffer.asShortBuffer().put(sBuffer);
```

Comment: To go the other way, you would have to do use `putShort(sBuffer[i])` in a loop (from `0` to `sBuffer.length`).

Comment: Or a different way... see my answer.

Comment: Hmmm,. this approach gave me a BufferUnderflowException

Answer (score 0):

Well... If you just want to read from the InputStream and store it on a byte[] variable, you only have to use the InputStream's read method:

```
InputStream inputStream;
byte[] bytes;

...

inputStream.read(bytes);
```

But, as you said you're working on an audio record system, I suggest you to look at the [AudioRecord Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html). You can easily use it to record sound and read the data.