# InputStream audio mixing (MODE_STREAM)

Tags: java, android, audio, buffer, inputstream

I'm making a drum sequencer in Android...

I'm writing to an `AudioTrack` in `MODE_STREAM`, so that I can achieve synchronized audio playback with all `InputStreams` (availible via a list of 'active' InputStreams, `activeStreams` in the code below)

The audio is always: PCM (WAV), 16bit Stereo 44100 Hz.

Obviously, I can't composite audio in real time on the UI thread, so I'm using an `AsyncTask` to queue up all the audio buffering.

I got buffered playback working, but when it comes to merging the buffers of two (or more) `InputStream`'s, the internet seems to be in some kind of debate of what to do next. "Convert the byte[] to short[]!", "No, do the bit mixing on-the-fly!", "But if you don't use shorts the byte Endianness is ignored!", "It gets ignored anyway!" - I don't even know any more.

**How do I mix the buffer of two or more InputStreams?** I don't understand why my current implementation is failing

I've tried like, 4 different StackOverflow solutions to convert the byte[] to short[] so I can add the samples together, but the conversion always instantly crashes Java with some cryptic error message that I can't get my head around. So now I give up. Here's my code implementing [one such StackOverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804972/how-make-short-from-input-stream)...

```
protected Long doInBackground(Object ... Object) {

  int bytesWritten = 0;
  InputStream inputStream;
  int si = 0, i = 0;

  //The combined buffers. The 'composition'
  short[] cBuffer = new short[Synth.AUDIO_BUFFER_SIZE];

  //The 'current buffer', the segment of inputStream audio.
  byte[] bBuffer = new byte[Synth.AUDIO_BUFFER_SIZE];

  //The 'current buffer', converted to short?
  short[] sBuffer = new short[Synth.AUDIO_BUFFER_SIZE];

  int curStreamNum;
  int numStreams = activeStreams.size();
  short mix;

  //Start with an empty 'composition'
  cBuffer = new short[Synth.AUDIO_BUFFER_SIZE];

  boolean bufferEmpty = false;
  try {
    while(true) { // keep going forever, until stopped or paused.
      for(curStreamNum = 0;curStreamNum < numStreams;curStreamNum++){
        inputStream = activeStreams.get(curStreamNum);
        i = inputStream.read(bBuffer);
        bufferEmpty = i<=-1;
        if(bufferEmpty){
          //Input stream buffer was empty. It's out of audio. Close and remove the stream.
          inputStream.close();
          activeStreams.remove(curStreamNum);
          curStreamNum--; numStreams--; continue; // hard continue.
        }else{
          //Take the now-read buffer, and convert to shorts.
          ByteBuffer.wrap(bBuffer).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().get(sBuffer);

          //Take the short buffer, merge into composition buffer.
          //TODO: Optimize by making the 'first layer' of the composition the first buffer, on its own.
          for(si=0;si<Synth.AUDIO_BUFFER_SIZE;si++){
            mix = (short) (sBuffer[si] + cBuffer[si]);
            //This part is probably completely wrong too. I'm not up to here yet to evaluate whats needed...
            if(mix >= 32767){
              mix = 32767;
            }else if (mix <= -32768){
              mix = -32768;
            }
            cBuffer[si] = mix;
          }
        }
      }
      track.write(sBuffer, 0, i);

      //It's always full; full buffer of silence, or of composited audio.
      totalBytesWritten += Synth.AUDIO_BUFFER_SIZE;

      //.. queueNewInputStreams ..
      publishProgress(totalBytesWritten);
      if (isCancelled()) break;
    }
  } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
  return Long.valueOf(totalBytesWritten);
}
```

I'm currently getting a `BufferUnderflowException` on this line: `ByteBuffer.wrap(bBuffer).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().get(sBuffer);`.

How is it possible to have buffer underrun? I'm only converting a byte[] to a short[].

Please help!

I've posted my whole function in the hopes that this more complete code sample and fairly adaptable usage can help other people out there.

(P.S. the byte[] to short[] conversion is followed by some flimsy hard clipping which I'm not even up to debugging yet, but advice there would also be appreciated)

Comment: Have you checked my answer? Any comment?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Will test your answer shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution seems almost good, I see two issues and a potential one:

1. the length of the short array: it MUST be the half of the byte array, otherwise you get the underflow
2. the sum of the short must be the average of the shorts and not just the sum, or you'll get just noise
3. (potential issue) the length of the array you read by InputStream cannot be totally free, since you have to sum 2bytes for every InputStream (then it must be an even array) and you should take care of mono vs. stereo audio files (if stereo you have 2bytes for the left channel and 2bytes for the right channel interleaved)

Here you can find a snippet that I would use to sum of two WAV array (16bit, mono)

```
    Random random = new Random();

    int bufferLength = 20;

    byte[] is1 = new byte[bufferLength];
    byte[] is2 = new byte[bufferLength];
    byte[] average = new byte[bufferLength];

    random.nextBytes(is1);
    random.nextBytes(is2);

    short[] shorts1 = new short[bufferLength/2];
    ByteBuffer.wrap(is1).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().get(shorts1);

    short[] shorts2 = new short[bufferLength/2];
    ByteBuffer.wrap(is2).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().get(shorts2);

    short[] result = new short[bufferLength/2];

    for (int i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
        result[i] = (short) ((shorts1[i] + shorts2[i])/2);
    }

    ByteBuffer.wrap(average).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer().put(result);
```

For a 32bit stereo, the solution could be

```
    Random random = new Random();

    int bufferLength = 8 * 50;

    byte[] is1 = new byte[bufferLength];
    byte[] is2 = new byte[bufferLength];
    byte[] average = new byte[bufferLength];

    random.nextBytes(is1);
    random.nextBytes(is2);

    System.out.println(bytesToHex(is1));
    System.out.println(bytesToHex(is2));

    int[] ints1 = new int[bufferLength/4];
    ByteBuffer.wrap(is1).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asIntBuffer().get(ints1);

    int[] ints2 = new int[bufferLength/4];
    ByteBuffer.wrap(is2).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asIntBuffer().get(ints2);

    int[] result = new int[bufferLength/4];

    for (int i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
        result[i] = ((ints1[i] + ints2[i])/2);
    }

    ByteBuffer.wrap(average).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asIntBuffer().put(result);
```

Comment: Looking over this, I'm pretty confident it will work. I'm pretty much ready to hand you the bounty on this. Thanks for your help! Could you possibly post a 32bit stereo variation of the answer? I assume it changes all instances of `/2` to `/8`... is that right? Or would I need to use `/4`, but produce two versions of `byte[] average` (one for left, one for right)

Comment: It's pretty simple: if you have a 32bit sample, then you need to sum int values (a int in Java is 4bytes->32bit). So you just need to modify the 2 to 4 and the 'asShortBuffer' to 'asIntBuffer'. About the left and the right: you have a stereo WAV file, the left sample is interleaved with the right one; that means that you have L R L R L R ok?

Comment: If you have a 32bit stereo PCM the number of bytes of a sample (left+right) is 64bit or 8 bytes for a left+right sample.

Comment: I didn't end up getting to test any of this, but I'm quite sure this should be enough info for me to get the solution working, so I'm just going to give you the bounty. Thanks again for your help!